# How to set a loop correctly in order to display all information

Tags: php, html

Trying to display all incorrect answers into a table for each question, but for some strange reason, I am recieving an empty answer in one of the rows. Now this is only happening in question 2 and question 2 is the only question which has multiple correct answers so I believe the problem I am having is I am not setting `$row_count` correctly but **my question is** how can it be set proerly to be able to display the missing answer which is `D`? The php fiddle to see the problem is here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps

Code below which sets row count for incorrect answers for a question which contains mutliple correct answers is below:

```
 <?php
        //remaining incorrect answers in separate row (if any) follows here
    if($row_count < $q_row_span - 1) 
    {
        for($i=($row_count + 1); $i<$q_row_span; $i++) { ?>     
            <tr>
               <td class="answertd"><?php echo$inc_ans[$i];?>
                  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[]" value="<?php echo$inc_ans[$i];?>">
               </td>

               <td class="answermarkstd">
                  <input class="individualMarks q<?php echo$questionNo?>_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" data-qnum="<?php echo$questionNo?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" />
               </td>
            </tr>
    <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that array you are iterating over `$ques_ans` with for() has a gap in keys.

`var_dump($ques_ans)` gives us:

```
array(3) {
  ... skipped for brevity
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  ... skipped for brevity
}
```

There is no element with the key `[1]`. It's because the function [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), which you use on line 49, preserves keys.

To quickly fix your code just to make it work without errors I added `array_values()` on line 51:

```php
$ques_ans[$questionNo] = array_values($q_incorrect_ans);    //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key
```

Though it might make no sense to your app logic. I just didn't dive in it. So check for that.

Comment: Is there a better way for me to use the array interset so that instead of displaying multiple sets of arrays for a question which has multiple answers, it is able to just have 1 set of array and remove the multiple correct answers in a question in one set. This is because I tested you fix with a different set of questions and answers and even that one has an incorrect answer missing